# Ubuntu 14.04 asking for pass phrase to unlock RSA key oddity.

Tags: ubuntu, rsa, passphrase

Sorry for the obscure title but I have no idea how to phrase this..

I am having an oddity occurring with my RSA key, I use RSA key authentication over SSH for all my servers and other services where possible.

Recently I have been doing commits to a custom GITLABS installation that uses my rsa key to authenticate and it has popped up asking for a pass phrase to unlock my key... Now the odd bit, the pass phrase that works is valid for my key from my home computer, but on the computer I am accessing GITLABS from does not use a pass phrase, however the phrase for my home computer unlocks my key anyway...

I have noticed this happen a couple of times on this computer and when it does happen the pass phrase is asked for every time I want to access git labs and each time I use my home computer pass phrase to unlock it. A reboot fixes the issue.

What the hell might be going on????

Kind Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Do you share the same private key between your home computer and work one?
Please try to connect to the git server from both boxes directly via ssh with -vv option:
  ssh -vv git@gitserver